# Correct typos in place names using Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a web form which asks for the user's address, but I would like to correct possible typos using the database underlying Google Maps. For example, when I search 'Amsterda' in Google Maps, it immediately jumps to Amsterdam.

Can I use Google Maps API for this?

Comment: Nice idea, will be interested to see if anything can be done with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes I use the [Google Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) to search for user's input. It corrects typos and returns one or more valid locations for the user's search. If it returns more than one, then I ask the user to clarify by choosing one.

Edit: It also breaks a user's input into lines of address, town/city, postcode, country which is great for storing neatly in a database if required

Hope that helps